# @media - detecting which browser

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working on an existing site and have to work within the current boundaries. I'm adding a new feature and in the css we have a number of `@media` blocks. So continuing with this ethos. I have introduced some styling that works with most browsers that we are targeting with the max-width set at 1200px. For a couple of browsers I need the same CSS kicking in at when `max-width is 1300px`, the browsers support the @media property. So I need to differentiate which browser is being used to target the correct @media property. All other CSS work across the browsers being targeted.

I guess I want something like `@media (max-width:1200px) and (browser = xxxxx)`

Comment: Maybe with js? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219779/identify-browser-and-os-with-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media queries for each browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480142/media-queries-for-each-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480142/media-queries-for-each-browser)

you can try to see  [this site](http://browserhacks.com/) for more insight